# TypeError "the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.main'" when importing from pydantic

Tags: python, import, typeerror, pydantic

I'm trying to use BaseModel from pydantic (2.6.3) in Python (3.9.5) using:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
```

The issue I'm having is that I get a TypeError stemming from importlib that pydantic apparently uses:

```
File "C:\MyProject\debug-x64\Python\python39.zip\site-packages\pydantic\__init__.py", line 383, in __getattr__
    module = import_module(module_name, package=package)
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 122, in import_module
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.main'
```

I can import 'ValidationError' from pydantic and use it without any issues.

I have tried all the usuals with uninstalling, reinstallig and trying different version of pydantic (back to 2.0) to no avail.

I'm guessing it's not necessarily specific to pydantic but maybe my project structure. Anyone who has encountered this?

Comment: What's your script name (and path)?

Comment: @CristiFati rest/search/routes.py